# Jacob connect to Remote Computer for WMI support

Tags: java, wmi, jacob

I'm trying to connect to a remote computer using java and Jacob in order to get some WMI Information about the remote computer.

For localhost I'm using the code below and it works fine.

```
    String host = "localhost";
    String connectStr = String.format("winmgmts:\\\\%s\\root\\CIMV2", host);

    ActiveXComponent axWMI = new ActiveXComponent(connectStr);
    // other code to get system information
```

But if I change localhost to another ip/hostname I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't find moniker
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.createInstanceNative(Native Method)
    at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.<init>(Dispatch.java:99)
    at com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent.<init>(ActiveXComponent.java:58)
    at easyticket.classes.WmiExtended.main(WmiExtended.java:28)
```

and the row that throws the exception is:

```
ActiveXComponent axWMI = new ActiveXComponent(connectStr);
```

**EDIT**

I tried passing username/password using `WbemScripting`

```
String host = "192.168.7.106";
ActiveXComponent axWMI = new ActiveXComponent("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
axWMI.invoke("ConnectServer", new Variant(host+",\"root\\cimv2\",\"username\",\"password\""));
```

but I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Invoke of: ConnectServer
Source: SWbemLocator
Description: The RPC server is unavailable.
```

**How can I solve it? How can I pass username/password and if is needed the domain???**

I'm using Windows 8 and I'm trying to connect to win8/win7/winxp/win2003server computers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some searches I managed to solve my problem...

Here's the code if anyone need it.

```
ActiveXComponent wmi = new ActiveXComponent("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");        

  Variant variantParameters[] = new Variant[4];
  variantParameters[0] = new Variant(_IPADDRESS);
  variantParameters[1] = new Variant("root\\cimv2");
  variantParameters[2] = new Variant("username");
  variantParameters[3] = new Variant("password");     
  ActiveXComponent axWMI;
try
{
    Variant conRet = wmi.invoke("ConnectServer", variantParameters);        
    axWMI = new ActiveXComponent(conRet.toDispatch());
}catch(ComFailException e)
{
    axWMI = null;
}
if (axWMI == null)
    return false;
```

Comment: Hi Marcx, could you please let me know that how can I use JACOB to read & write to a COM interface remotly ?

Comment: so what is the difference between winmgmts:\\\\%s\\root\\CIMV2 and WbemScripting.SWbemLocator